# Return most recent active rows of one sql table based on activity of another table

Tags: sql, sorting, datetime, inner-join

I am making a small posting forum as a learning project to teach myself Bootstrap/PhP/SQL.

The behavior of the main forum will display a list of topics ranked by their most recent responses. So a topic named **Cookies** that had *a reply one minute ago would sit above* a topic named **Pie** that had a reply two days and so on and so forth.

I have constructed 2 tables, *frm_THREAD* and *frm_POST* and have been able to write an *appropriate join SQL statement* to pull the data I want back in one query rather than several. I want to push this so that *I am pulling back only the data I need*, no extra.

Right now my SQL returns a table like this with 13 rows.

[image]

I want to return a table with three rows as show here. Each row representing an active topic, the topics can be sorted by datatime
[image]

I think that the final magic is in how I sort/order the results, but I haven't chanced on to the correct phrasing to figure out how to parse out the unnecessary data. I want to only return only one row for each topic, the row returned should be the most recent active row which is a combination of the two tables queried that can be sorted by datetime so that I can properly display the activity - show what is most active/of interest first. post table which would have the date/timestamp of recent activity that can then be used to sort the topic id/name --  for brevity sake, I sliced out things like topic name and post comments etc. I tried to create a simple barebones bit of SQL that concentrates on what I need doing which I can then expand on once I have the final solution.

this is my SQL in it's current state.

```
SELECT       t.ThreadID,  t.isTITLE, 
             p.postID, p.isACTIVE, p.dateCREATED 
FROM         frm_THREAD   AS   t
INNER JOIN   frm_POST     AS   p 
ON           t.ThreadID   =    .threadID
ORDER BY     p.dateCREATED, t.ThreadID
```

**TO SUMMARIZE:** I want to return one row representing each topic, with the rows being sorted based on activity as determined by the timestamp from the response reply found in the post table.

HERE IS THE THREAD AND POST TABLES I AM DRAWING ON - The yellow highlights shows the data i am specifically trying to pull back from the frm_POST data with it being merged with the frm_THREAD data

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I'm using SQL which I stated above "Bootstrap/PhP/SQL"   Not sure what you mean by tag'? When I posted the question, I selected 'SQL' which is what I'm using for the database   - I'm very new / self-teaching / exploring

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT ThreadID, isTITLE, postID, isACTIVE, dateCREATED
FROM (SELECT t.ThreadID, t.isTITLE, p.postID, p.isACTIVE, p.dateCREATED,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ThreadID ORDER BY p.DateCreated DESC) as seqnum
      FROM frm_THREAD t JOIN
           frm_POST p 
           ON t.ThreadID = p.threadID
     ) pt
ORDER BY p.dateCREATED, t.ThreadID;
```

Comment: I ran this SQL in Adminer to test it, got an error. I broke the SQL down attempting to  dig in to try to figure out the error without much luck solving it:SELECT
   ThreadID,
   isTITLE,
   postID,
   isACTIVE,
   dateCREATED 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         t.ThreadID,
         t.isTITLE,
         p.postID,
         p.isACTIVE,
         p.dateCREATED,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ThreadID 
      ORDER BY
         p.DateCreated DESC) as seqnum 
      FROM
         frm_THREAD AS t 
         JOIN
            frm_POST AS p 
            ON t.ThreadID = p.threadID

Comment: Ran it through some syntax checkers and things like that and received a report back suggesting that something is off with this part of the statement " (PARTITION BY t.ThreadID ..." Syntax seem to be fine, I am thinking maybe its the PARTITION BY? - digging in, any help is appreciated - and thanks for you help thus far Gordon!